# Salvar arquivo enviado em Ajax no backend node

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

Olá tenho um backend em node e estou recebendo esta requisição ajax

```
var arquivo = $("#assinatura");
arquivo.on('change', function (event) {
  if (arquivo[0].files.length == 0)
    return false;

var data = new FormData();
data.append('assinatura', arquivo[0].files[0]); 
console.log(data);
$.ajax({
    url: "/salvarAssinatura",
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){

  }
});
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a saber como recebo o arquivo no backend e salvo em uma pasta...

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar algo parecido com o código abaixo.

```
var path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs');
// ...
app.post('/salvarAssinatura', function (req, res) {
    var tempPath = req.files.file.path,
        targetPath = path.resolve('./uploads/image.png');
        fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Upload completed!");
        });
    }
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Usei multer, mas obrigado pela dica.